# Chrome URL bar that remembers past URLs better

Tags: gratis, chrome, url, history

The Chrome URL bar is bad at remembering URLs.

For instance if I visit `http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html` and then a week later I type "CMIS" in the URL bar, Chrome will propose me various Google searches, rather than the URL I visited last week.

What Chrome extension could replace the URL bar with something that suggests me past URLs? It should remember at least 2 months worth of URLs.

Comment: How about Firefox? ;)

Comment: @Kodiologist: very true, Firefox is perfect in that regard. But this question is specifically about Chrome :-) My personal conspiracy theory is that Chrome wants its users to use Google every time.